# Need help for Ordinary Kriging in R

Tags: r, kriging, gstat

I have collected a set of observations, and my goal is to perform Ordinary Kriging using the `gstat` package to interpolate these observations onto a regular grid. I'm encountering difficulties in selecting the variogram parameter, and the Kriging variance values I'm obtaining are significantly larger than expected. While I anticipate errors in the 2 cm to 4 cm range at the grid nodes, the Kriging results show errors between 4.2 to 4.5 meters. I'm seeking assistance to identify and rectify any potential issues in my approach. I'm open to guidance and suggestions, whether it's related to the code or the underlying concepts. Below is my complete code for reference.
The figure of my actual experimental and fitted variogram is as shown below:
[image]

```
    # Load the sf library for spatial data handling
library(sf)
library(gstat)
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)

# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

world2 <- ne_coastline(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
countries <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf") 

    # Create a dummy data frame
dummy_data <- data.frame(
  lat = runif(1000, min = 21, max = 27),    # Random latitude values between 21 and 27
  lon = runif(1000, min = 23, max = 27), # Random longitude values between 23 and 27
  height_m = runif(1000, min = 14, max = 28), # Random height values between 14 and 28 meters
  SD_heights = runif(1000, min = 0.02, max = 0.04) # Random SD of the heights at observed locations meters
)

# Define the extent of the grid
lat_min <- 21
lat_max <- 27
long_min <- 23
long_max <- 27

# Create a sequence of latitude and longitude values
lat_values <- seq(lat_min, lat_max, by = 0.5)
long_values <- seq(long_min, long_max, by = 0.5)

# Create the grid points
grid_point <- expand.grid(lat = lat_values, lon = long_values)

# plot 
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world2, size = 1, colour = "black") +
  geom_sf(data= countries,  color= "#E5E5E5", fill = "#E5E5E5") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(23, 27), ylim = c(21, 27)) +
  geom_point(data= grid_point, aes(x = lon, y = lat), color ="red")+
  geom_point(data= dummy_data, aes(x = lon, y = lat))


# Ordinary Kriging
# Compute the Empirical Variogram:
# Define the original CRS (Assuming WGS 84)
original_crs <- st_crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
# Create a data frame with the original latitude and longitude data
data_df <- dummy_data

# Convert the data frame to a spatial data frame (sf object) with the original CRS
data_sf <- st_as_sf(data_df, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = original_crs)

# Define the target projection (e.g., UTM Zone 33N)
target_crs <- st_crs("+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m")

# Project the data to the target CRS
data_sf_projected <- st_transform(data_sf, target_crs)
coor_m <- st_coordinates(data_sf_projected) %>% as.data.frame()

# Detrend the data using linear regression
# Create a data frame with the heights and coordinates
data_combined <- data.frame(
  h = data_df$height_m,
  lon = coor_m$X,
  lat = coor_m$Y
)
# Perform linear regression
lm_model <- lm(h ~ lon + lat, data = data_combined)

# Extract the coefficients a, b, and c
a <- coef(lm_model)[1]
b <- coef(lm_model)[2]
c <- coef(lm_model)[3]

detrended_h <- resid(lm_model)

# Add the detrended variable to the spatial data frame
data_sf_projected$detrended_h <- detrended_h

# Grid points for interpolation in the target CRS
# Create a data frame for the grid points in the target CRS
interp_sf <- st_as_sf(grid_point, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = original_crs)

# Reproject interp_sf to the target CRS
interp_sf_reprojected <- st_transform(interp_sf, crs = target_crs)

# Set a smaller cutoff value for the empirical variogram (adjust as needed)
cutoff_value <- 300000
search_radius <- 20000

# Compute the empirical variogram with the new cutoff
variogram_model_detrended <- variogram(detrended_h ~ 1, data = data_sf_projected, width = search_radius,  cutoff = cutoff_value)
plot(variogram_model_detrended)

# Fit a variogram model to the empirical variogram
variogram_fit_detrended <- fit.variogram(variogram_model_detrended, model = vgm(psill = 17.3, model = "Exp", range = 250000, nugget = 16.2))


# Plot the empirical variogram
plot(variogram_model_detrended, plot.type = "cloud", main = "Empirical and Fitted Variograms")


# Create a data frame of the empirical variogram
empirical_variogram_df <- data.frame(dist = variogram_model_detrended$dist,
                                     gamma = variogram_model_detrended$gamma)


preds = variogramLine(variogram_fit_detrended, maxdist = max(variogram_model_detrended$dist))
head(preds)


# Create the ggplot plot
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = empirical_variogram_df, aes(x = dist/1e3, y = gamma, color = "Empirical model"), alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_line(data = preds, aes(x = dist/1e3, y = gamma, color ="Analytical model"))+
  labs(title = "Empirical and Fitted Variograms",
       x = "Distance [km]",
       y = "Semivariance") +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_color_manual(name= "", breaks=c('Empirical model', 'Analytical model'),
                     values=c('Empirical model'='red', 'Analytical model'='blue'))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(16, NA), 
                                                  linetype = c(NA, 1)))) +
  theme(#plot.title = element_text(color = "black", face="bold", size = 24),
    plot.title = element_blank(),
    plot.subtitle = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 11,
                              margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)),
    axis.text = element_text(color="black", size = 10),
    # panel.background = element_blank(),
    # panel.grid = element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_text(color = "black",face="bold",  size = 11),
    legend.title.align = 0.5 ,
    legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 10), 
    legend.key.height = unit(0.7, 'cm'), 
    #legend.key.width = unit(2.5, 'cm'),
    legend.position = "bottom", 
    aspect.ratio = 1/2)

# Perform kriging

kriged_detrended <- krige(detrended_h ~ 1, locations = data_sf_projected, newdata = interp_sf_reprojected, vgm(psill = 17.3, model = "Exp", range = 250000, nugget = 16.2))
coor_kriged_detrended <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(kriged_detrended))
kriged_detrended_df <- data.frame(
  h = kriged_detrended$var1.pred,
  h_var = kriged_detrended$var1.var,
  lon = coor_kriged_detrended$X,
  lat = coor_kriged_detrended$Y)

kriged_predicted_h <- kriged_detrended_df$h + (coef(lm_model)[1] + coef(lm_model)[2]* kriged_detrended_df$lon+ coef(lm_model)[3] * kriged_detrended_df$lat)
head(kriged_predicted_h)

summary(sqrt(kriged_detrended_df$h_var))
```

Comment: Why do you expect such a small error? Your data is completely non-spatially correlated, and so your variogram is probably picking up nothing but noise - what does it look like? Your data has a range of 14 to 28, ie 14 metres, and so its variance is (28-14)^2/12 =~ 16, then the standard error is the square root of that which is 4 metres.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. However, my original observations have values in the range of 14 to 28 m and their error in the range of 2 cm to 4 cm. That is why I am expecting the values at the unsampled locations to be in the same range of accuracy.

Comment: The data frame I provided is a dummy, not actual observations. Here, I am adding another column containing the standard deviation of the heights at the observed locations.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Your data has no spatial correlation. Kriging can add no more information that it has in the data, and the data is random uniform between approx 14 and 28 and that has a variance of 16 and so a SE of 4 metres. If your data has some spatial correlation then you should expect the variance to be less than 16 at close distances to the data points, but will tend to 16 at large distances from the data points, since the spatial correlation will have decayed by then and the only information left is the mean and variance. "close" and "large" distance depends on the fit parameters.

Comment: My actual data indeed exhibits spatial correlation not like the dummy data I provided above. It's important to highlight that Kriging was applied to the detrended data points. The Ordinary Kriging (OK) produced the residuals and their variances at grid nodes. After that, I re-added the trend to the Kriged values. However, I encountered a challenge in calculating the variance or error after adding the trend back in. I'm currently grappling with how to perform error propagation or incorporate the overall variance of the data before detrending

Comment: What I am sure about is that the standard deviation of the interpolated height values at the grid nodes should not exceed 4 cm. What might be amiss or what crucial detail I may have overlooked in my process?

Comment: The grid nodes are the locations where you are trying to predict, yes? They're not locations where you have data, right? In the dummy data example in your code the variogram is flat, all the way from 0 up to 300km, and so the predictions at the grid nodes don't get any information from the data points, and so take on the variance of the data. 16m. Is that understood? However for data with spatial correlation like the variogram in the picture now, I'd expect grid points *close* to data points to have small variance and grid points further away to have large variance....

Comment: the 2-4cm uncertainty is only going to happen at 0 distance (ie if the grid points are on a data point) and if you fit a variogram model with a nugget parameter fixed at 0.02m, and that's probably not distinguishable from 0 with the data you have.

Comment: One more question. Based on the experimental and fitted variogram figures, it seems that the range is approximately 192 km. I'd like to clarify the difference between the range and the search radius. If I want to perform local ordinary kriging, considering only data points within a 20 km radius, is that correct? I don't intend to use global kriging, which involves all observation points.